# Can you use ConfigureAwait(false) with Task.WhenAny()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, configureawait

I'm trying to implement a task based interleaving pattern similar to below.

This logic is in a library and so I'm trying to make use of ConfigureAwait(false) as I don't see a reason that the task must resume in the same context.

In the below example line 3 will fail as Task1 and Task2 are not actually Tasks but instead [ConfiguredTaskAwaitable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.configuredtaskawaitable?view=netframework-4.8) 
Further using these Task1 and Task2 directly in Task.WhenAny(Task1,Task2) it will also fail as it only accepts Tasks not the ConfiguredTaskAwaitable class.

```
var Task1 = await GetTask1Async().ConfigureAwait(false);
var Task2 = await GetTask2Async().ConfigureAwait(false);
var tasks = new List<Task<string>>{Task1 ,Task2};

while(tasks.Count > 0)
{
    try
    {
        Task<Bitmap> readyTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        tasks.Remove(readyTask);

        string result = await readyTask ;
        ProcessTask(result);
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Is there a reason why I shouldn't use ConfigureAwait(false) with Task.WhenAny()? 
Or is there some step I am missing that I should apply to the output of the ConfigureAwait() before passing it to the Task.WhenAny()?

Comment: The duplicate is for `WhenAll` instead of `WhenAny` but it is the exact same problem. You use configure await when you await, not when you create the tasks.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it's so obvious now thanks!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete

Comment: Mnemonic: `ConfigureAwait` configures the `await`, not the task.